# Getting The Package name out of Activity on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the list of the installed browsers on my android. I found a code that provide me the list of activities that handle URL:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                                                 PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
    String name = info.name;
    String pkgName = info.resolvePackageName;
}
```

I am able to get the activity names, but the package name is always null.
Is there a way to get the package name? or is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks,

RC

Answer (score 0):

You will need to match it with packageInfo objects.

```
List<PackageInfo> temp = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for(PackageInfo info: temp) {
  String pkg = info.packageName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
    String name = info.activityInfo.name;
    String pkgName = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
}
```